# React js changes running in local macine in cmd

Tags: reactjs

I have downloaded react master  code from GitHub and able to run it. But I want to some change in that code and then run again but don't know what command to use the run the changes through command line in local host.

Comment: It's a very vague question. React is a library which you use in an application, Please share the application code.

Comment: Can you show the package.json file of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

normally if you have a nodejs application that would be

```
npm start
```

or yarn

```
yarn start
```